# avoir l'air vs. sembler

Tags: expressions

Pour moi les constructions "**avoir l'air** (d'être)" et "**sembler** (être)" ont l'air d'être/semblent être interchangeables (à part dans des phrases comme "il semble qu'elle ne viendra pas"). Est-ce que c'est bien le cas ou est-ce que je n'ai pas tout à fait saisi comment il faut utiliser ces deux constructions?  Voici quelques exemples de phrases où je me demande si les deux constructions sont aussi convenables:

> Il n'a pas l'air content = Il ne semble pas content

> Isabel a l'air d'être une personne sûre d'elle = Isabel semble être une personne sûre d'elle

> Ça a l'air de marcher très bien au travail = Ça semble marcher très bien au travail

Comment: Je reconnais que la formule n'est pas la plus élégante mais je peux m'imaginer dire "Il y a l'air qu'elle ne viendra pas".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pas de différence de sens dans les trois exemples, la différence tient plutôt au registre. **Sembler** est soutenu alors qu'**avoir l'air** est utilisé à tous les registres.

**Avoir l'air** présente aussi la particularité de pouvoir se comprendre de deux façons, la première où **air** est suivi d'un attribut du sujet :

> **Elle** n'a pas l'air **contente**.

La deuxième, plus rare, où **air** est suivi d'un adjectif épithète :

> Elle n'a pas l'**air content**.